# tree algorithm implementation c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, tree

I have some issues resolving an algorithm used to find all posible combinations taking elements from N diferents lists (where N>=2 && N<=7 -> this number is fixed and I can make a diferent method for each N).
The problems goes as this:
I have five dictionaries:

```
IDictionary<int, MyEnum> listOne; 
IDictionary<int, MyEnum> listTwo;
IDictionary<int, MyEnum> listThree;
IDictionary<int, MyEnum> listFour;
IDictionary<int, MyEnum> listN;

enum MyEnum
    {
    MyEnumOne,
    MyEnumTwo,
    MyEnumThree,
    MyEnumFour,
    MyEnumFive,
    MyEnumOther
   }
```

which can have any number of elements (not more than 100, and most of the time they will have between 32 and 64 elements)
and where MyEnum is a simple name enum with some values.

For each possible combination, I have some method which examinates the combination and checks if it satisfies some conditions,and if they are satisfied stores some data based on the combination.

I have tried simple nested iterations using foreachs for each list, which as expected, take eons to run!

Any help, as where I should start, what should I do, or event what I should not do will be more than welcome!, also if more info is needed, please feel free to ask!

****EDIT:
a combination, based on five lists as shown before would be, for example:

```
(MyEnumOne, MyEnumOne, MyEnumFour, MyEnumFive, MyEnumTwo)
```

and, as this combination, can appear several times (as MyEnumOne value can be many times on listOne, etc), I have to also, keep record of how many times does this combination happens.

Comment: Can you define what a combination looks like, an some example logic that you use on the combination?  Can you define what all possible combinations means?

Comment: If the method is generic you have no choice but to examine every combination and it will take eons to run. A short but typical input-> output is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this kind of problems easily with LINQ.

```
var solutions = from pair1 in listOne
                where IsCandidate(pair1)
                from pair2 in listTwo
                where IsCandidate(pair1, pair2)
                from pair3 in listThree
                where IsCandidate(pair1, pair2, pair3)
                from pair4 in listFour
                where IsCandidate(pair1, pair2, pair3, pair4)
                from pair5 in listFive
                where IsCandidate(pair1, pair2, pair3, pair4, pair5)
                from pair6 in listSix
                where IsCandidate(pair1, pair2, pair3, pair4, pair5, pair6)
                from pair7 in listSeven
                where IsSolution(pair1, pair2, pair3, pair4, pair5, pair6, pair7)
                select new { pair1, pair2, pair3, pair4, pair5, pair6, pair7 };
```

Of course this approach is valid only because the number of lists is known at compile time. An alternative approach would be to have a generic way of building the possible combinations, as [Eric Lippert shows in his post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx).

All those intermediate `where` all over the query, are to filter out invalid combinations as soon as possible.

**EDIT**

Fixed solution to count efficiently how many times a same combination happens, ignoring the keys of the original source.

To achieve this, I'm going to apply a transformation to each dictionary. I'm going to transform each dictionary into a new dictionary, where the key would be the enum value, and the value would be the number of times that enum values happens in the original dictionary.

```
IDictionary<MyEnum, int> CountOccurrences(IEnumerable<MyEnum> values)
{
    return (from e in values group e by e).ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Count());
}

var solutions = from p1 in CountOccurrences(listOne.Values)
                where IsCandidate(p1)
                from p2 in CountOccurrences(listTwo.Values)
                where IsCandidate(p1, p2)
                from p3 in CountOccurrences(listThree.Values)
                where IsCandidate(p1, p2, p3)
                from p4 in CountOccurrences(listFour.Values)
                where IsCandidate(p1, p2, p3, p4)
                from p5 in CountOccurrences(listFive.Values)
                where IsCandidate(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5)
                from p6 in CountOccurrences(listSix.Values)
                where IsCandidate(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6)
                from p7 in CountOccurrences(listSeven.Values)
                where IsSolution(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7)
                select new {
                    E1 = p1.Key,
                    E2 = p2.Key,
                    E3 = p3.Key,
                    E4 = p4.Key,
                    E5 = p5.Key,
                    E6 = p6.Key,
                    E7 = p7.Key,
                    Times = p1.Value * p2.Value * p3.Value * p4.Value * p5.Value * p6.Value * p7.Value
                };
```

Comment: this almost solved my problem, now, how can I satisfy my last edit, on which I need to have on that solution only diferent combinations, and the number of times each of them appears on this solution?

Comment: Is the `int` key of each dictionary meaningful? What I mean, is it useful to be allowed to check candidate solutions using that `int`? Can it be filtered before returning each combination?

Comment: the key is not needed here, and can be ignored, it's used to get a combination from a tuple of ints within the application.

Comment: Giving a second read to your edit, I'm now confused if my last edit is what you need, or if you need to tell how many times a same combination can happen. Tell me if you need the other.

Comment: It's the second thing you mentioned what I need: how many times a same combination can happen, but not to all combinations, only relevant ones, the other adds to the garbageCombination count!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, with such problems you should try to *construct* the solutions and not blindly go through the entire search space looking for them.

I'm assuming that what you really need to do is this:
- you have N lists, each list i having L(i) elements.
- you want to generate all combinations of length N, where the first element comes from the first list, the second element from the second list and so on.

There doesn't seem to be any way to avoid generating all the combinations the hard way.
All 100 elements ^ N ~ 10^14... which will take eons.

I second the request for small samples and conditions that need to be satisfied.