# Count number of pre-defined combinations, based on definition list

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

This question, is a more especific case of this one:

[Tree algorithm implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860000/tree-algorithm-implementation-c)
who was asked by another user.

I have three diferent list, each of them having a predefined number of elements (64), from an enum

```
enum Values
            {
                G0,G1,G2,G3,G4,G5,G6,G7,G8,G9,G10
            }
```

the Lists:

```
List<Values> list1;
List<Values> list2;
List<Values> list3;
```

The values on them can be generated randomly:

```
//for each list    
Random rand = new Random();
for(int i=1; i<=64; i++) listN.Add((Values)rand.Next(1,12));
```

Also I have an struct called:

```
struct ValuesCombination
        {
            List<Values> Combination { get; set; }
        }
```

which is used to store all relevant combinations (generated using the simbols from `list1`, `list2`, `list3`)

I also have a list, which contains all posible combinations:

```
List<ValuesCombination> combinations;
```

Some combination examples:

```
combinations.Add(new ValuesCombination(){ Values.G0, Values.G0, Values.G0}); //#comb1
combinations.Add(new ValuesCombination(){ Values.G0, Values.G0});//#comb2
combinations.Add(new ValuesCombination(){ Values.G1, Values.G1});//#comb3
combinations.Add(new ValuesCombination(){ Values.G2, Values.G2});//#comb4
```

Combinations are of lenght 2 or 3.

`#comb1` is satisfied by getting a `G0` from `list1`, `G0` from `list2` and `G0` from `list3`,
but `#comb2` is satisfied by getting `G0` from `list1`, `G0` from `list2` and with any `Value` except `G0` from `list3`

What I need?

Based on my combinations list I need to count the number of ocurrences each of my combinations on this list have, getting one element from each list.

I do not need the formula for each combination, I need it the long way, as I we pick a pencil and do this.

```
list1[1] list2[1] list3[1] = G1, G1, G1 -> satisfies = true! G1G1G1 combination++
list1[1] list2[1] list3[2] = G1, G1, G2 -> satisfies = true! G1G1 combination++
list1[1] list2[1] list3[3] = G1, G1, G0 -> satisfies = true! G1G1 combination++
...
list1[n] list2[n] list3[n] = GX, GX, Gx -> satisfies??
```

I need this to run as fast as possible, because with this I want to create an application that gives me the probability of each combination while I change the Values of each list.

Im using visual studio 2010 with c# 4.0.